# Amount of occurrences of a value in a field, for each row

Tags: mysql, sql, subtotal

I want to be able to retrieve, for each row, the **number of total appearances of one value of one field**.

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`country` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO `events` (`country`) VALUES
('es'), ('fr'), ('uk'),
('uk'), ('es'), ('uk'),
('fr'), ('it'), ('es'),
('es'), ('it'), ('uk'),
('fr'), ('es'), ('de')
```

That is, given [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f6bb2/2), I want to able to **add a field to the results**, that conditionally **adds the number of appearances of each value of field `country`**.

```
SELECT * from `events`;

ID  | COUNTRY | TIMES
----+---------+------
1   | es      | 5
2   | fr      | 3
3   | uk      | 4
4   | uk      | 4
5   | es      | 5
6   | uk      | 4
7   | fr      | 3
8   | it      | 2
9   | es      | 5
10  | es      | 5
11  | it      | 2
12  | uk      | 4
13  | fr      | 3
14  | es      | 5
15  | de      | 1
```

If possible, it would be great that partial results (`LIMIT x, y`) would still return total sums for each field:

```
SELECT * from `events` LIMIT 3, 7;

ID  | COUNTRY | TIMES
----+---------+------
4   | uk      | 4
5   | es      | 5
6   | uk      | 4
7   | fr      | 3
8   | it      | 2
9   | es      | 5
10  | es      | 5
```

As per [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f6bb2/3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select e.*,
       (select count(*) from events e2 where e2.country = e.country
       ) as times
from `events` e;
```

It seems to meet your needs.  If you want to actually change the table:

```
alter table events add times unsigned;

update events e
    set times = (select count(*) from events e2 where e2.country = e.country);
```

Comment: I don't know how I didn't see it :) compare to the table itself! Thanks